# Using PHP to convert from one date format to another

Tags: php, datetime, date, format

I'm looking to convert a date from one format to another.

This is my current date format:

```
2011-08-15 15:35:58
```

and I need to convert it into:

```
Mon, 15/08/2011 15:35
```

I can quite easily create this by cutting the last 3 characters from the time and then using str_replace to change '-' into '/' and so on, but I was wondering if there is there is a way to do this automatically using the date() function or something similar. I am also not sure how to generate the day of the week e.g. 'Mon', 'Tues' etc.

Hope someone can help.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP convert one date into another date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/php-convert-one-date-into-another-date-format)

Comment: Formatting options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I read this one, i didnt think  it helped

Comment: +1 What's with the irrelevant downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done easily using a combination of [`date()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$newDate = date('D, d/m/Y H:i', strtotime($oldDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions:

```
$d = strtotime("2011-08-15 15:35:58");

var_dump(date( 'D, d/n/Y H:i',$d));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work fine:

```
<?

$time = strtotime("2011-08-15 15:35:58");
echo date("D, d/m/y H:m", $time);
```

But be carefull, strtotime depends on timezone settings.